# DHTMLX mobile scheduler event detail view height issue?

Tags: javascript, mobile, scheduler, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have integrated dhtmlx mobile scheduler. When details text is large it will cut down because dhtmlx scheduler event detail view take static height in style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue using following command.

```
$$("scheduler").$$("eventTemplate").$view.style='';
```

May be it help some else.